# txt file icon not showing

Tags: windows-8

On Windows 8, my .txt file association has no icon. It is quite annoying, and has been going on for several months now.

I've tried to un-associate it using the folder-->options--file types, I've tried to change the association, delete the icon cache, and even tried using ftype and assoc. nada.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The first step is to restore the default file assosiations.  Have you done that?  The script file to do this can be found by doing a google search

Comment: Is it displaying no icon at ALL, or the wrong/default icon?

Answer (score 0):

Try repairing Icons with Tune Up Utilities. This doesn't happen much but you can correct it with Tune Up Utilities or try this: 
Right-Click on the programs > Properties > Compatability Tab > Click the option at the bottom under Privilege Level that says "Run this program as an administrator". This might also solve it.

And as you said, confirm that you deleted the icon cache correctly...

1. Kill explorer process
2. cmd /c del %userprofile%\AppData\Local\IconCache.db /a

or

1. Go to Regedit (Registry Editor)
2. HKEY_LOCAL MACHINE / SOFTWARE / Microsoft / WINDOWS NT / CurrenVersion / Winlogon
3. Find 'Shell', double click
4. Edit the value to Explorer.exe

or

1. It should help. If it doesnt, type gpedit.msc
2. Go to User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Desktop
3. open Properties of Hide and disable all items on the desktop

or

Find it here - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2422299

After anything you have tried, Restart your system

Comment: The linked URL currently redirects to https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/icons-are-not-displayed-for-certain-files-in-windows-7-83126d0e-d1cf-dcdd-6b27-78dbd25c706c - I did think of updating it, but the archived version at https://web.archive.org/web/20140208155813/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2422299 has a list of Windows versions it applies to (basically a lot of 7 and Vista versions) and I don't know if the article's content is valid for any versions later than 7.